# Eventhandler not getting unsubscribed

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, delegates

In my silverlight application, I am passing a method `GetListCallBack` to a delegate parameter of another method `GetEmployees` in Repository class which attaches that delegate as eventhandler to completed event of an async service call.

EmpViewModel Class:

```
public class EmpViewModel
{
  private IRepository EMPRepository = null;

  //constructor
  public EmpViewModel
  {
    this.EMPRepository= new Repository();
  }

  public void GetList()
  {
     this.EMPRepository.GetEmployees(xyz, this.GetListCallBack);

  }

  public void GetAnotherList()
  {
     this.EMPRepository.GetEmployees(pqr, this.GetAnotherListCallBack);

  }


  private void GetListCallBack(object sender, GetListCompletedEventArgs args)
  {
        if (args.Error == null)
        {
            this.collection1.Clear();
            this.collection1 = args.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            //do sth
        }
  }

  public void GetAnotherListCallback(object sender, GetListCompletedEventArgs args)
  {
     //do sth with collection1

  }

}
```

Repository Class:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{

    private readonly ServiceClient _client=null ;

    public Repository()
    {
        _client = new ServiceClient(Binding, Endpoint);
    }

    public void GetEmployees(int xyz, EventHandler<GetListCompletedEventArgs> eventHandler)
    {
        _client.GetListCompleted -= eventHandler;
        _client.GetListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetListCompletedEventArgs>(eventHandler);
        _client.GetListAsync(xyz);
    }
}
```

Now, when a call to the method `GetList()` has been completed and then if I call another method `GetAnotherList()` in same class `EmpViewModel`, then `GetListCallBack` method gets called again before `GetAnotherListCallBack` gets called.

This is probably happening as both methods get subscribed to the event.

As you can see, I have explicitly unsubscribed the eventhandler from the callback event but still the eventhandler is getting invoked.
Can anyone please suggest where I may be going wrong?

EDIT:

When I use a local variable instead of using `this.EMPRepository` to call the `Repository` method it works well as both CallBack methods are passed to different instances of `Repository` class and only the attched CallBack method gets fired

```
public class EmpViewModel
{

 public void GetList()
 {
  EMPRepository = new Repository();
  EMPRepository.GetEmployees(xyz, this.GetListCallBack);
 }

public void GetAnotherList()
{
EMPRepository = new Repository();
EMPRepository.GetEmployees(pqr, this.GetAnotherListCallBack);
}  

--------
```

Comment: Can you change the code for `ServiceClient` class? It the thing that should be fixed.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn ServiceClient class is autogenerated by VS when a service reference is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
_client.GetListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetListCompletedEventArgs>(eventHandler);
```

is (seen from a functional point of view) the same as:

```
_client.GetListCompleted += eventHandler;
```

And now you immediate see the problem. Your code is:

```
_client.GetListCompleted -= eventHandler;
_client.GetListCompleted += eventHandler;
```

Why remove an eventhandler if you add it in the next line.

I guess you want to remove the old eventhandler and add a new one. So your function should get a delegate to the old eventhandler to remove. Something like this:

```
public void GetEmployees(int xyz, EventHandler<GetListCompletedEventArgs> oldEventHandler, EventHandler<GetListCompletedEventArgs> newEventHandler)
{
    _client.GetListCompleted -= oldEventHandler;
    _client.GetListCompleted += newEventHandler;
    _client.GetListAsync(xyz);
}
```

But is that even possible?

If you have control over `ServiceClient.GetListCompleted`, why not remove the `event` keyword and just assign that delegate, like:

```
public void GetEmployees(int xyz, EventHandler<GetListCompletedEventArgs> eventHandler)
{
    _client.GetListCompleted = eventHandler;
    _client.GetListAsync(xyz);
}
```

Or... if the delegate is only called once per GetListASync:

```
public void GetEmployees(int xyz, EventHandler<GetListCompletedEventArgs> eventHandler)
{
    _client.GetListCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        eventHandler(sender, e); 
        _client.GetListCompleted -= eventHandler;
    };
    _client.GetListAsync(xyz);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All the points raised by you are indeed spot on and extremely helpful. The last code block is certainly an excellent way to unsubscribe eventhandler. But even after using this approach I am facing same issue and both the call back methods are getting called one after another. However, when I use a local variable instead of using 'this.EMPRepository' to call the 'Repository' method it works well as both CallBack methods are passed to different instances of 'Repository' class and only the attched CallBack method gets fired.